# Laravel 4 Eloquent: how to select where value is in array?

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

Suppose I have a Model with db record like this:

```
row1: id: 1  users:["1","2","3"] 
row2: id: 2  users:["3","4","5"]
```

Users are data formatted from `json_encode(array($user_id))`. Now I want to retrieve the model if `user_id` in `users`. So if my `user_id` is 2, i will  retrieve only row 1, but if my `user_id` is 3, i will retrieve both `row1` and `row2`.

I tried something like `Model::whereIn('users', $user_id)->get();`, it does not work, any other ways to achieve this Eloquent way?

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are storing your user id in session or something, so your_id refers to the id assigned to yourself.

```
Model::where('id','!=',your_id)->get();
```

This would return your all the rows, except the id = your_id

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, i'm trying to retrieve the model based on `users` column, not `id` column (that `id` has nothing to do with `$user_id`, it is the id of the model itself).

Comment: Thats not best practice , you must implement pivot table concept. or else retrieve and process.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a very Eloquent way of doing this. But since you use json_encode, we can assume that all data is formatted the same way, and do something like this:

```
Model::where('users', 'like', '%"'.$user_id.'"%')->get();
```

This should work. Your situation is usually best handled with pivot tables, but of course you don't *have* to use them like the other guy said.

Comment: this approach came in my mind at first time, unfortunately when i have a data like this ['13','14','24'], $user_id = 1 still counts (well, since i realize there's no real way to do this, i already had redesign my table, thanks for the answer)

Comment: No, it doesn't. It literally looks for ``"1"``, with anything before and after. Your example doesn't contain ``"1"``, so it won't find the 13, 14, or 24 in your example array. But I'm glad you found a solution! :)